# Convert a list of long to list of nullable long

Tags: c#

I have a list of long :

```
List<long> carIds;
```

I want to convert it to :

```
List<long?> ncarIds;
```

I have done it that way:

```
foreach(var item in carIds)
{
    long? id = (int?)item;
    ncarIds.Add(id);
}
```

Any idea of how to do this in one line?

Comment: Why do you cast to `int?`?

Answer (score 3):

With casting an Linq

```
List<long> carIds = new List<long>() { 1L, 2L };
List<long?> ncarIds = carIds.Cast<long?>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following LINQ-statement:

```
ncarIds.AddRange(carIds.Cast<long?>());
```

Note that this still loops internally so there's no performance gain here.